# Azure control condition not working even though results are equal

Tags: azure-devops

I have a task with a control condition `and(always(), eq(variables['storageExists'], 'banana'))` I believe this would result into true if the value of `$storageExists` is equal to `banana`.

I have a script that set `banana` on `storageExsists`:

```
 Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=storageExist;]banana"
```

Than in a following task I have a inline function:

```
Write-Host $env:storageExist
```

[image]

But the task with the control condition fails:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo storageExists vs storageExist

variable=storageExist;] should be variable=storageExists]

Comment: Oh wauw. Thanks a lot, tunnel vision I guess.